# module 'cv2.ml' has no attribute 'dtree_create'

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am building a decision tree with OpenCV. As far as i know,we can create an empty decision tree using the following code. Its showing error that  module 'cv2.ml' has no attribute 'dtree_create'. I know its something related to CV's version but what is the new code to create a decision tree using OpenCV version 3?

```
#Constructing the tree
import cv2
dtree=cv2.ml.dtree_create()
```

what is the new replacement of "dtree_create()". Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always good to check the documentation for these kind of changes. [Here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d8/d89/classcv_1_1ml_1_1DTrees.html#aa0ae71ed85f63d2ea809402c0f19d602) is the link for OpenCV version 3.4.5, and for python the code would be like this:

```
#Constructing the tree
import cv2
dtree=cv.ml.DTrees_create()
```

You can also use [`dir(cv2.ml)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) to see which are the valid attributes of the object (in this case cv2.ml). As result I get:

```
>>> dir(cv2.ml)
['ANN_MLP_ANNEAL', 'ANN_MLP_BACKPROP', 'ANN_MLP_GAUSSIAN', 'ANN_MLP_IDENTITY', 'ANN_MLP_LEAKYRELU', 'ANN_MLP_NO_INPUT_SCALE', 'ANN_MLP_NO_OUTPUT_SCALE', 'ANN_MLP_RELU', 'ANN_MLP_RPROP', 'ANN_MLP_SIGMOID_SYM', 'ANN_MLP_UPDATE_WEIGHTS', 'ANN_MLP_create', 'ANN_MLP_load', 'BOOST_DISCRETE', 'BOOST_GENTLE', 'BOOST_LOGIT', 'BOOST_REAL', 'Boost_DISCRETE', 'Boost_GENTLE', 'Boost_LOGIT', 'Boost_REAL', 'Boost_create', 'Boost_load', 'COL_SAMPLE', 'DTREES_PREDICT_AUTO', 'DTREES_PREDICT_MASK', 'DTREES_PREDICT_MAX_VOTE', 'DTREES_PREDICT_SUM', 'DTrees_PREDICT_AUTO', 'DTrees_PREDICT_MASK', 'DTrees_PREDICT_MAX_VOTE', 'DTrees_PREDICT_SUM', 'DTrees_create', 'DTrees_load', 'EM_COV_MAT_DEFAULT', 'EM_COV_MAT_DIAGONAL', 'EM_COV_MAT_GENERIC', 'EM_COV_MAT_SPHERICAL', 'EM_DEFAULT_MAX_ITERS', 'EM_DEFAULT_NCLUSTERS', 'EM_START_AUTO_STEP', 'EM_START_E_STEP', 'EM_START_M_STEP', 'EM_create', 'EM_load', 'KNEAREST_BRUTE_FORCE', 'KNEAREST_KDTREE', 'KNearest_BRUTE_FORCE', 'KNearest_KDTREE', 'KNearest_create', 'LOGISTIC_REGRESSION_BATCH', 'LOGISTIC_REGRESSION_MINI_BATCH', 'LOGISTIC_REGRESSION_REG_DISABLE', 'LOGISTIC_REGRESSION_REG_L1', 'LOGISTIC_REGRESSION_REG_L2', 'LogisticRegression_BATCH', 'LogisticRegression_MINI_BATCH', 'LogisticRegression_REG_DISABLE', 'LogisticRegression_REG_L1', 'LogisticRegression_REG_L2', 'LogisticRegression_create', 'LogisticRegression_load', 'NormalBayesClassifier_create', 'NormalBayesClassifier_load', 'ParamGrid_create', 'ROW_SAMPLE', 'RTrees_create', 'RTrees_load', 'STAT_MODEL_COMPRESSED_INPUT', 'STAT_MODEL_PREPROCESSED_INPUT', 'STAT_MODEL_RAW_OUTPUT', 'STAT_MODEL_UPDATE_MODEL', 'SVMSGD_ASGD', 'SVMSGD_HARD_MARGIN', 'SVMSGD_SGD', 'SVMSGD_SOFT_MARGIN', 'SVMSGD_create', 'SVMSGD_load', 'SVM_C', 'SVM_CHI2', 'SVM_COEF', 'SVM_CUSTOM', 'SVM_C_SVC', 'SVM_DEGREE', 'SVM_EPS_SVR', 'SVM_GAMMA', 'SVM_INTER', 'SVM_LINEAR', 'SVM_NU', 'SVM_NU_SVC', 'SVM_NU_SVR', 'SVM_ONE_CLASS', 'SVM_P', 'SVM_POLY', 'SVM_RBF', 'SVM_SIGMOID', 'SVM_create', 'SVM_getDefaultGridPtr', 'SVM_load', 'StatModel_COMPRESSED_INPUT', 'StatModel_PREPROCESSED_INPUT', 'StatModel_RAW_OUTPUT', 'StatModel_UPDATE_MODEL', 'TEST_ERROR', 'TRAIN_ERROR', 'TrainData_create', 'TrainData_getSubVector', 'VAR_CATEGORICAL', 'VAR_NUMERICAL', 'VAR_ORDERED', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']
```

In which you can see DTrees_create, which is the answer.

Comment: @Sonu you are welcome, If it solves your question please accept it, for other people with similar problems find faster the answer.